# Infer object type from object of objects

Tags: typescript

I don't really know how to describe this, so I will demonstrate it to the best of my ability:

```
type MetaObject <SomeObject> = {
  categoryOne: {
    [ key in keyof SomeObject ]?: (this: SomeObject) => string;
  };

  categoryTwo?: {
    [ key in keyof SomeObject ]?: SomeObject[key];
  };

  categoryThree?: {
    [ key in keyof SomeObject ]?: number;
  };
};

export const returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject: <T> (metaObject: MetaObject<T>) => T;
```

I want `returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject` to be able to infer at least the keys of the returned object, even if it lacks information about the values, based on the `MetaObject` provided to the function, but it seems unable to do this. For instance,

```
const someObject = returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject({
  categoryOne?: {
    a: () => 'hello',
    b: () => 'world',
  },

  categoryTwo: {
    b: 'a value',
    c: 'another value'
    d: 4346364
  },

  categoryThree: {
    x: 2,
    y: 75,
    z: 900
  }
});
```

TS only infers the type of `SomeObject` based on the object provided to `categoryOne`, so it ends up as

```
{
  a: unknown;
  b: unknown;
}
```

ignoring everything else, including the definition that would provide an actual value type in `categoryTwo`.

Is there a way I can get the interpreter to consider all the sub-objects when inferring the type of `SomeObject`?

Comment: Your definition of `MetaObject` doesn't play nicely with TS's inference algorithm, which assumes there are *some* restrictions and generally does not synthesize unions or intersections except in particular conditions.  My inclination here would be to make it generic in three different type parameters and then do the manipulation of these type parameters yourself, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NVkVBm).  Does that address the question and meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! I think so. My goal is to extract a definition of `SomeObject` out of the objects in `MetaObject`, and I think your example does the trick.

Comment: @jcalz I have tried your method in the actual code I needed this solution for and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple *inference sites* for a generic type parameter, such as the different appearances of `T` in the expanded definition of the `metaObject` parameter's type in `returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject`, the compiler uses heuristics to determine how to infer `T`.  It will assign each inference site a "priority", and infer from the highest-priority site or sites.  It usually does not synthesize [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) by combining the various candidates.  Instead it infers `T` from some of them and checks it against the remaining ones.  This is often what people want to see, and what it's doing in your case... but sometimes it isn't what people want.

There are various GitHub issues asking for ways to annotate call signatures to give
developers more control over this inference, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to block inference from some sites, or [microsoft/TypeScript#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312) to allow unions.  In your case it looks like you'd want an intersection (because [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) is [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)).  There's no direct support for this kind of thing, though.

---

Instead, if you want more control over inference, you should rewrite your call signatures to give you more control.   In your case it looks like you hardly ever want to *reject* a call to `returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject()` (or at least that's out of scope for the question as asked), and instead infer an intersection of the different `T` types mentioned in the different properties.  So let's just use a separate type parameter for each of these appearances, and manually synthesize the intersection from them:

```
type MetaObject<T1, T2 = T1, T3 = T1> = {
  categoryOne: {
    [K in keyof T1]?: (this: Id<T1 & T2 & T3>) => string;
  };

  categoryTwo?: {
    [K in keyof T2]?: T2[K];
  };

  categoryThree?: {
    [K in keyof T3]?: number;
  };
};

type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;

declare const returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject: <T1, T2, T3>(
  metaObject: MetaObject<T1, T2, T3>) => Id<T1 & T2 & T3>;
```

The `Id<T>` type is really just a way of formatting the type `T` more nicely (assuming it's just an object type or intersection of object types) by collapsing intersections into single object types; so `Id<{a: 0} & {b: 1} & {c: 2}>` is `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}`.

You can still write `MetaObject<T>`, which uses [generic defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to evaluate to `MetaObject<T, T, T>`, which you can verify is the same as your original version (assuming `Id<T & T & T>` is the same as `T`, which it usually is).  But now we can write `returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject()` to be generic in `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`, and infer these type parametes from `metaObject` of type `MetaObject<T1, T2, T3>`, and return `Id<T1 & T2 & T3>`.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const someObject = returnSomeObjectBasedOnMetaObject({
  categoryOne: {
    a: () => 'hello',
    b: () => 'world',
  },

  categoryTwo: {
    b: 'a value',
    c: 'another value',
    d: 4346364
  },

  categoryThree: {
    x: 2,
    y: 75,
    z: 900
  }
});

/*
const someObject: {
    a: unknown;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: number;
    x: unknown;
    y: unknown;
    z: unknown;
}
*/
```

Looks good.  Those `unknown` properties are the best the compiler can do, but `b`, `c`, and `d` are strongly typed because of `categoryTwo`.

Since this meets your needs I won't go any further, but it's definitely possible there are edge cases where this still doesn't behave as you'd like.  Often these cases can be accommodated, but sometimes they can't... eventually you might hit a situation where inference breaks down and you need to manually specify the type parameters.  But I'll stop here!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-a12oROtro1A9x1t1B07dHs9aOeayu1xut9rGw-1yJN+eu2+nzoFNoxxHIA)